# Instal Eclipse XML Development Tools in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: xml, eclipse, aptana3

I have installed Aptana studio 3 as a stand alone app on my laptop , now I want to integrate the Eclipse XML development tools. 
 I have tried the help menu. That is 
 
-----------------------------------help
 
--------------------------------------install new software 
----------------------------------------------------available software 

 but there is no url to link the eclipse site.
 I copied these urls into the available software dialogue box.

```html
"Eclipse Project Test Site" - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

The Eclipse Project repository - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5

The Eclipse Project repository - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/R-3.7.2-201202080800
```

but I cannot find the XML plugins.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I get what you are going through. You need to install the XPath evaluation package. As per you steps mentioned in adding more plugins, you just need to add the following site:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stoupa91/eclipse-xpath-evaluation-plugin/master/eclipse-xpath-evaluation-plugin-update-site/

Then install XPath Evaluation package.

The site that contains this information is available here:
"github.com/stoupa91/eclipse-xpath-evaluation-plugin"

The tutorial is available here (at minute 4:43 of 5:45)
https://www.lynda.com/XML-tutorials/Installing-developer-tools/145930/164602-4.html